# Add/Removing a CSS text color based on the hovering over another element/class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) and trying to get the styling a little different. Basically, when I hover over a menu with a ul, the dropdown menu is fine etc. When hovering over an element in that dropdown, the text color is fine because I have that element styed with a :hover.

When I am not hovering over that element, it uses the color of the top level.

I want it to remain white - Please ignore the difference in background colors, I was trying something out.

My CSS
http://pastebin.com/Hy1Rdwxb

Do I have to use jQuery .addClass to get this to stay white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is what is coloring it:

```
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
        background:             #ae9b9d;
        outline:                0;
        color: #eee !important; 
}
```

You'll want to change/add `.sf-menu li:hover` to `.sf-menu li:hover > a` to get the effect. The trouble is that it will not be colored on hover because there is a more specific styling for the `a` tag itself. The above allows for `a` tags directly below the `li` to be styled with the CSS.

Note that the `>` operator is to not style all of the elements directly below, just the one you want, but [won't work in IE 6](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3E) (since some of your styles seem to indicate you'll support it, [which you shouldn't](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) unless your audience forces your hand) which means you will still see this discoloration in IE 6.

Comment: I don't mind omitting IE6, and embrace it - but that CSS is actually superfish mostly.

Comment: You can add your own styling then. Just put `.sf-menu li:hover > a { color: #eee !important; }` in your own CSS code and you can see if the result sticks.

Comment: This does work, hover when hovering outside of the dropdown it uses the top level color again. Any tricks/ideas?

Comment: Possible jQuery mouseout on the .menuClass -- addClass 'whiteText' or something.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't user Superfish but my guess would be it has to do with their `.sfHover` class. I don't know when that is applied though. You can try adding `.sf-menu li.sfHover > a` to the above as well, but with seeing a live example I'm not sure I can help much more. If it doesn't work, maybe try posting an example to http://jsfiddle.net